# How to construct JSON file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to take a CSV file and construct a JSON file with the values. The JSON file needs to be in a very specific format to be imported into Azure.

I am very new to Python, in fact this is the first time I'm using Python properly.

I have started to use Pandas to convert the csv into a dataframe, and then doing a small amount of formatting before converting into Json. This is a good start but it's not quite formatted properly. Please see below.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users***Required_data.csv")

filtered = df['Work Item Type'].str.contains('Task')

dftest = df[filtered]
dftest = dftest.rename(columns={"Work Item    
Type":"System.WorkItemType","Title":"System.Title","AssignedTo":"System.AssignedTo","State":"System.State","Tags":"System.Tags","Description":"System.Description"})
dftest["System.AreaPath"] = "**********"

dftest.to_json(r"C:\\Users****\\Required_datatest.json",indent=4,orient="records")`
```

This gives me the following format in Json - An array of objects

source data:

[image: source]

My Attempt result:

```
[
    {
        "ID":15898,
        "System.WorkItemType":"Task",
        "System.Title":"TK 1.2.1 -  Example data",
        "System.AssignedTo":null,
        "System.State":"New",
        "System.Tags":null,
        "Parent":15887,
        "System.Description":"Example data",
        "System.AreaPath":"Example data"
    }
]
```

However i'm trying to build the following structure:

Target data in Json format:

```
{
      "count": 36,
      "value": [
        {
          "id": 487,
          "rev": 1,
          "fields": {
            "System.AreaPath": "Example data",
            "System.TeamProject": "Example data",
            "System.IterationPath": "Example data",
            "System.WorkItemType": "Task",
            "System.State": "New",
            "System.Reason": "New",
            "System.CreatedDate": "2021-02-22T19:13:24.81Z",
            "System.CreatedBy": "Example data",
            "System.ChangedDate": "2021-02-22T19:13:24.81Z",
            "System.ChangedBy": "Example data",
            "System.Title": "Example data",
            "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort": 0.0,
            "System.Description": "Example data",
            "System.AssignedTo": null,
            "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork": 0.0,
            "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority": 2.0,
            "System.BoardLane": null,
            "System.Tags": null,
            "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps": null,
            "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Parameters": null,
            "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.LocalDataSource": null,
            "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus": null,
            "System.History": null
          },
          "relations": [
            {
              "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
              "url": "Example data",
              "attributes": {
                "isLocked": "false",
                "name": "Parent"
              }
            }
          ],
          "url": "Example data"
        }
    ]
    }
```

As you can see the array is then wrapped inside of another object which has 'count' and 'value'. My dataframe is then stored inside of 'fields' in the 2nd picture which is required.

Can anyone offer guidance here? I'm a bit stuck. If Pandas is not the correct tool please let me know. Please also provide the easiest solution as i'm still learning and would like to understand it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how the source data is structured and how it would be transformed into the format you want. It might help if you include an (anonymized) sample of the source data.

Comment: My initial thoughts are that `to_json` won't give you exactly what you want here, so you might have to call `to_dict`, do some transformations on the dictionary yourself, serialise the resulting dict to JSON and save it /https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: @SimonCrowe Thanks Simon. I'll update to show better source and target data.

Comment: @SimonCrowe - Updated post. I guess the tricky thing is that the target data is expecting more data. However, it's the same data for every item in the array so i can do that myself with values it expects. The thing i'm struggling with is manipulating the target json to nest objects etc. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for adding more data. I've looked over this and am wondering how "`rev"`, `"relations"` and `"url"` would be arrived at. `"rev"` could just be set to `1` but for the other two I can't see where the information would come from.

Comment: @SimonCrowe You're correct. It wouldn't come from the source data. Some properties i'd have to set as a constant value because they're the same each time. Relations is a bit more tricky because i'd have to construct that again using a value from the 'parent' property. I'm trying to take it 1 step at a time for now but i will hit further problems with this as you say. 
The target data is expecting more when i input it into Azure, than i have in the source data. I'm going to have to add that data myself once i have the formatting correct.

Thank you

Comment: I've added an answer with some code. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function like `tranform_data` below to do the additional transformation you need.

```py
import pandas as pd


REVISION = 1


def exclude_keys(to_exclude: dict, *excluded_keys) -> dict:
    def predicate(key_val):
        key, val = key_val
        return key not in excluded_keys
    return dict(filter(predicate, to_exclude.items()))


def transform_data(to_transform: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:
    records = to_transform.to_dict("records")
    values = [
        {
            "id": record["ID"],
            "rev": REVISION,
            "fields": exclude_keys(record, "ID")
        }
        for record in records
    ]
    return {
        "count": len(records),
        "value": values
    }
```

Calling `transform_data` should have this result:

```py
>>> transform_data(dftest)
{'count': 1,
 'value': [{'id': 15898,
   'rev': 1,
   'fields': {'System.WorkItemType': 'Task',
    'System.Title': 'TK 1.2.1 -  Example data',
    'System.AssignedTo': None,
    'System.State': 'New',
    'System.Tags': None,
    'Parent': 15887,
    'System.Description': 'Example data',
    'System.AreaPath': 'Example data'}}]}
>>> import json
>>> with open("~/path/to/output.json", "w") as fd: json.dump(transform_data(dftest), fd)
```

You should be able to adapt that code for any transformations or additional information you need to add to the data.

It might have been possible to do what I've done with raw Python using Pandas, but as far as I know, Pandas is best suited to flat tabular data rather than the nested data you need. Marshmallow might also be worth looking at as it handles nested JSON well: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html